# OleDbAdapter errors, Hides variable in an enclosing block error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, syntax-error

I've run into some issues/errors regarding some of my OleDb commands. They are shown in the image below:

[image]

My goal of the project is to import information *(in this case, text)* into an Access Database *(named Database1)* based on which checkboxes are checked. From there the data will be counted based on a couple of different factors, and then used by a coordinating Visual Studio project to display the data in graphs.

I would only like records to be *added*, not deleted.

I have a feeling that I am missing something very small; maybe just using the wrong value type or inserting the wrong variables. I apologize for the code being very amateur; after all I am new to the programming/ coding world. I'm just not sure how to start fixing these errors.

Here is the whole section of code for reference, if needed:

```
Private Sub InputInformation(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImporttBUT.Click

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    MsgBox("OPEN")
    Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
                                                        .DataSource = "S:\software\Melton System\DPD & DEL (KPI)\Database1.accdb",
                                                         .PersistSecurityInfo = False}
    Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand{"SELECT * from [DataCollection] WHERE ID = 0",
                                     New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString)}
                                     End Using


    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Dim usertables As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(con)
    Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder
    cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(dt)

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Database1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
    Dim myrow As DataRow = dt.Rows.Add

    With dt.Rows.Add
        .Item("M/Y Of LOG") = Me.MonthList2021.SelectedItem
        .Item("TIME OF LOG") = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        .Item("USER") = UserName
        '' ADD STK ITEM HERE ONCE AUTOFILL IS COMPLETE
        If MissedPartCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSED PART") = MissedPartCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedPartCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSED PART") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("NOT IN EPICOR") = NotInEpicorCHKB.Text
        ElseIf NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("NOT IN EPICOR") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSED BUYOUT") = MissedBuyoutCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSED BUYOUT") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If NonStockCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSED NON STOCK ITEM") = NonStockCHKB.Text
        ElseIf NonStockCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSED NON STOCK ITEM") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSED STOCK ITEM") = MissedSTKItemCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSED STOCK ITEM") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSED AUTOMATED") = MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSED AUTOMATED") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSING PRINTS AFTER QUANTITY") = MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSING PRINTS AFTER QUANTITY") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("MISSED PRINT NOT SENT TO CHAD") = MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Text
        ElseIf MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("MISSED PRINT NOT SENT TO CHAD") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If OtherCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("OTHER") = OtherTXTB.Text
        ElseIf OtherCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("OTHER") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("ADDED MISSING DIMENSION") = AddedMissingDimCHKB.Text
        ElseIf AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("ADDED MISSING DIMENSION") = "NEATOL"
        End If
        If FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = True Then
            .Item("FIXED DIMENSION") = FixedDimensionCHKB.Text
        ElseIf FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = False Then
            .Item("FIXED DIMENSION") = "NEATOL"
        End If
    End With

    da.update(dt)

    con.Close()
    MsgBox("CLOSED")

    MissedPartCHKB.Checked = False

    MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = False

    NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked = False

    NonStockCHKB.Checked = False

    MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = False

    MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = False

    MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = False

    MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = False

    AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = False

    FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = False

    OtherCHKB.Checked = False

    OtherTXTB.Text = ""
    ' eventually change the month list to automatically select based on the current date
    MonthList2021.SelectedItem = False
End Sub
```

Here is a preview of my access database:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add a new record or are you updating an existing record?

Comment: @Mary Adding  a new record!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important database object to have in a `Using` block is a connection.

If the expression you are evaluating in an `If` statement returns a `Boolean`, like the `Checked` property of a check box, you don't need the `= True`. Since the value of this property can only be `True` or `False`, you do not need to recheck it with an `ElseIf`. An `Else` will do.

I certainly hope that Time Log field is a `Date`.

In the Insert statement, the field names with spaces and/or reserved words need to be in brackets [ ]. Access ignores the names of the parameters. We use them to make the code readable. For Access the order that the parameters appear in the sql statement must match the order which they are added to the parameters collection.

Instead of retrieving data you don't use in the Select query and hitting the database twice, once with the `.Fill` and once with `.Update`, we will just do the insert of the new record directly. If you do have occasion to use a `DataAdapter`, it will `Open` and `Close` the connection for you if it finds the connection closed. However, if it finds it `Open` it will leave it `Open`.

Notice that the connection is not opened until directly before the `.Execute...` and is closed and disposed with the `End Using` along with the command.

I moved the resetting of the controls to a separate `Sub`. Try to keep your methods doing only one thing. Although `.SelectedItem` takes any `Object`, `False` will not do what you expect.

```
Private Sub InputInformation(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImporttBUT.Click
    Dim strSql = "Insert Into [Data Collection] (
            [M/Y Of LOG],
            [TIME OF LOG],
            [USER],
            [MISSED PART],
            [NOT IN EPICOR],
            [MISSED BUYOUT],
            [MISSED NON STOCK ITEM],
            [MISSED STOCK ITEM],
            [MISSED AUTOMATED],
            [MISSING PRINTS AFTER QUANTITY],
            [MISSED PRINT NOT SENT TO CHAD],
            OTHER,
            [ADDED MISSING DIMENSION],
            [FIXED DIMENSION]
            )
            Values (@MYLog,@TimeLog, @User, @MissedPart, @NotEpicor, MissedBuyout, @MissedNonStock, @MissedStock,@MissedAutomated, @MissedPrints, @NotSent, @Other, @MissingDimension, @FixedDimension);
            "

    Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database1ConnectionString),
            cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSql, con)

        With cmdSQL.Parameters
            .Add("@MYLog", OleDbType.Date, 100).Value = CDate(MonthList2021.SelectedItem.ToString)
            .Add("@TimeLog", OleDbType.Date, 100).Value = DateTime.Now
            .Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = UserName
            .Add("@MissedPart", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If MissedPartCHKB.Checked Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPart").Value = MissedPartCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPart").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@NotEpicor", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If NotInEpicorCHKB.Checked Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotEpicor").Value = NotInEpicorCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotEpicor").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@MissedBuyout", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If MissedBuyoutCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedBuyout").Value = MissedBuyoutCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedBuyout").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@MissedNonStock", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If NonStockCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedNonStock").Value = NonStockCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedNonStock").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@MissedStock", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If MissedSTKItemCHKB.Checked = True Then
                .cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedStock").Value = MissedSTKItemCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedStock").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@MissedAutomated", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedAutomated").Value = MissedAutomatedPartCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedAutomated").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@MissedPrints", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPrints").Value = MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissedPrints").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@NotSent", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotSent").Value = MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@NotSent").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@Other", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If OtherCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@Other").Value = OtherTXTB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@Other").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@MissingDimension", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If AddedMissingDimCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissingDimension").Value = AddedMissingDimCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@MissingDimension").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
            .Add("@FixedDimension", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)
            If FixedDimensionCHKB.Checked = True Then
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@FixedDimension").Value = FixedDimensionCHKB.Text
            Else
                cmdSQL.Parameters("@FixedDimension").Value = "NEATOL"
            End If
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    ResetControls()
End Sub

Private Sub ResetControls()
    Dim lstChkBx As New List(Of CheckBox) From {MissedPartCHKB, MissedAutomatedPartCHKB, NotInEpicorCHKB, NonStockCHKB, MissedSTKItemCHKB, MissedBuyoutCHKB, MissedPrintsNOTSentChadCHKB, MissingPrintAfterQTYCHKB, AddedMissingDimCHKB, FixedDimensionCHKB, OtherCHKB}

    For Each chk As CheckBox In lstChkBx
        chk.Checked = False
    Next
    OtherTXTB.Text = ""
    ' eventually change the month list to automatically select based on the current date
    'If this is a ListBox
    MonthList2021.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub
```

Preview of my Access Database:

[image]

Comment: Okay, it runs perfectly until it gets to the cmdSQL.ExcecuteNonQuery(), the error is that it couldn't find the output table. I confirmed the table is called "DataCollection", but for some reason they aren't connecting.

Comment: Check the connection string and make sure it is pointing to the database that has a DataCollection table.

Comment: Solved the connection string issue, now the same line is giving me a System.Data.OleDbException 'syntax error in INSERT INTO statement'. Is it possible that one of the column names might be incorrect and that's what is throwing it off? I may have accidentally used the wrong name or something.

Comment: Does the table have a Primary Key? Is it an auto-number field?

Comment: Check the fields for each of the parameters to see if the field types are correct. I had to guess at the field types and size.

Comment: What would determine the field size? The parameter names are correct.  I will add a screenshot of the table to this post.

Comment: If you could include the view of the table as in my EDIT. Field size is only shown for string types like Text etc. Just the list of field names and datatypes will be helpful.

Comment: I am interested in the datatypes mainly, the OleDbType.VarChar. See what the types of the fields are in the database. The names of the fields won't match exactly

Comment: Mary, I have updated the preview of my database.

Comment: I can see one problem right away. The table name is wrong. You had DataCollection. The correct name is [Data Collection]. There is a space between Data and Collection.

Comment: Okay I fixed the name, however I'm still getting the error. Also thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't realize from your original question that M/Y Of LOG  was a DateTime field. In addition to correcting the table name correct this line as follows. `.Add("@MYLog", OleDbType.Date, 100).Value = CDate(MonthList2021.SelectedItem.ToString)`

Comment: I replaced that line of code, however a new error occurs: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: When I changed to the correct table name I forgot the brackets for Data Collection (contains a space) `Insert Into [Data Collection]`

Comment: Okay, so this error is present again in this line "cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()": System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.' -  Is the ExcecuteNonQuery() nessecary over maybe refresh()? Again, new at this, so sorry if that's completely wrong.

Comment: `.ExecuteNonQuery` is what runs the query. I have set up a table in Access that matches yours and run the query from vb.net an it works. Check that your code exactly matches mine.

Comment: I corrected it from looking at another accdb file. However, I'm still getting the error. I think at this point this thread has shifted too far away from the original question, so I will be creating another question containing my current error so I don't mislead anyone that looks at this thread. If you'd like to, you are more than welcome to hop on that question as well. Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: Good idea. I am sorry we couldn't get it running. My next idea is to get the parameters values set up separately in another method and passing the values to this method. All those ifs in the middle of the data access code look messy.

Comment: There's no need to be sorry. Again, thank you so much for the help. Being new to programming, this stuff just doesn't come to me as easy right now. I agree the if then statements are messy; if there's a way around them I would be more than happy to get rid of them.

Comment: Hi, Mary! Just wanted to let you know that the program works now, all thanks to your help!